# How to draw the middle half of a sphere (in code)

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, 3d, mesh

I'm trying to create the middle half of a sphere. Basically to create a sphere, stack numbers and slice numbers are given, and there are two variables `phi` (for slices) and `theta` (for stacks) responsible for how much to progress. And the process is divided into creating bottom cap, body, and top cap (as seen below). To achieve middle half (`theta` of middle 50% as below), we need to omit the caps, and somehow modify the body. I was playing around with stack numbers (`1/4*stackNumbers to 3/4*stackNumbers`) but didn't give the result I wanted.

How should I modify the sphere generation to achieve the middle half (**`pi/4 <theta <pi*3/4`**)? My overall problem is how can I split the sphere into 3 different parts upper 25%, middle 50%, and bottom 25%? (25% in terms of angle, i.e. `theta`)

Here is the popular code for generating a sphere programmatically:

[image]

```
private void generateSphere(int stackNumber, int sliceNumber, boolean facingOut) {
    int capVertexNumber = 3 * sliceNumber;
    int bodyVertexNumber = 4 * sliceNumber * (stackNumber - 2);
    int vertexNumber = (2 * capVertexNumber) + bodyVertexNumber;
    int triangleNumber = (2 * capVertexNumber) + (6 * sliceNumber * (stackNumber - 2));

    vertices = new float[3 * vertexNumber];
    normals = new float[3 * vertexNumber];
    texCoords = new float[2 * vertexNumber];
    indices = new char[triangleNumber];

    // bottom cap
    // createCap(stackNumber, sliceNumber, false, facingOut);

    // body
    createBody(stackNumber, sliceNumber, facingOut);

    // top cap
    createCap(stackNumber, sliceNumber, true, facingOut);
}

private void createCap(int stackNumber, int sliceNumber, boolean top, boolean facingOut) {

    float stackPercentage0;
    float stackPercentage1;

    if (!top) {
        stackPercentage0 = ((float) (stackNumber - 1) / stackNumber);
        stackPercentage1 = 1.0f;

    } else {
        stackPercentage0 = (1.0f / stackNumber);
        stackPercentage1 = 0.0f;
    }

    float t0 = stackPercentage0;
    float t1 = stackPercentage1;
    double theta0 = stackPercentage0 * Math.PI;
    double theta1 = stackPercentage1 * Math.PI;
    double cosTheta0 = Math.cos(theta0);
    double sinTheta0 = Math.sin(theta0);
    double cosTheta1 = Math.cos(theta1);
    double sinTheta1 = Math.sin(theta1);

    for (int slice = 0; slice < sliceNumber; slice++) {
        float slicePercentage0 = ((float) (slice) / sliceNumber);
        float slicePercentage1 = ((float) (slice + 1) / sliceNumber);
        double phi0 = slicePercentage0 * 2.0 * Math.PI;
        double phi1 = slicePercentage1 * 2.0 * Math.PI;
        float s0, s1;
        if (facingOut) {
            s0 = 1 - slicePercentage0;
            s1 = 1 - slicePercentage1;
        } else {
            s0 = slicePercentage0;
            s1 = slicePercentage1;
        }
        float s2 = (s0 + s1) / 2.0f;
        double cosPhi0 = Math.cos(phi0);
        double sinPhi0 = Math.sin(phi0);
        double cosPhi1 = Math.cos(phi1);
        double sinPhi1 = Math.sin(phi1);

        float x0 = (float) (sinTheta0 * cosPhi0);
        float y0 = (float) cosTheta0;
        float z0 = (float) (sinTheta0 * sinPhi0);

        float x1 = (float) (sinTheta0 * cosPhi1);
        float y1 = (float) cosTheta0;
        float z1 = (float) (sinTheta0 * sinPhi1);

        float x2 = (float) (sinTheta1 * cosPhi0);
        float y2 = (float) cosTheta1;
        float z2 = (float) (sinTheta1 * sinPhi0);

        vertices[vertexCount + 0] = x0;
        vertices[vertexCount + 1] = y0;
        vertices[vertexCount + 2] = z0;

        vertices[vertexCount + 3] = x1;
        vertices[vertexCount + 4] = y1;
        vertices[vertexCount + 5] = z1;

        vertices[vertexCount + 6] = x2;
        vertices[vertexCount + 7] = y2;
        vertices[vertexCount + 8] = z2;

        if (facingOut) {
            normals[vertexCount + 0] = x0;
            normals[vertexCount + 1] = y0;
            normals[vertexCount + 2] = z0;

            normals[vertexCount + 3] = x1;
            normals[vertexCount + 4] = y1;
            normals[vertexCount + 5] = z1;

            normals[vertexCount + 6] = x2;
            normals[vertexCount + 7] = y2;
            normals[vertexCount + 8] = z2;
        } else {
            normals[vertexCount + 0] = -x0;
            normals[vertexCount + 1] = -y0;
            normals[vertexCount + 2] = -z0;

            normals[vertexCount + 3] = -x1;
            normals[vertexCount + 4] = -y1;
            normals[vertexCount + 5] = -z1;

            normals[vertexCount + 6] = -x2;
            normals[vertexCount + 7] = -y2;
            normals[vertexCount + 8] = -z2;
        }

        texCoords[texCoordCount + 0] = s0;
        texCoords[texCoordCount + 1] = t0;
        texCoords[texCoordCount + 2] = s1;
        texCoords[texCoordCount + 3] = t0;
        texCoords[texCoordCount + 4] = s2;
        texCoords[texCoordCount + 5] = t1;

        if ((facingOut && top) || (!facingOut && !top)) {
            indices[indexCount + 0] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);
            indices[indexCount + 1] = (char) (triangleCount + 0);
            indices[indexCount + 2] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);
        } else {
            indices[indexCount + 0] = (char) (triangleCount + 0);
            indices[indexCount + 1] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);
            indices[indexCount + 2] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);
        }

        vertexCount += 9;
        texCoordCount += 6;
        indexCount += 3;
        triangleCount += 3;
    }

}

private void createBody(int stackNumber, int sliceNumber, boolean facingOut) {
    for (int stack = 1; stack < stackNumber - 1; stack++) {
        float stackPercentage0 = ((float) (stack) / stackNumber);
        float stackPercentage1 = ((float) (stack + 1) / stackNumber);

        float t0 = stackPercentage0;
        float t1 = stackPercentage1;

        double theta0 = stackPercentage0 * Math.PI;
        double theta1 = stackPercentage1 * Math.PI;
        double cosTheta0 = Math.cos(theta0);
        double sinTheta0 = Math.sin(theta0);
        double cosTheta1 = Math.cos(theta1);
        double sinTheta1 = Math.sin(theta1);

        for (int slice = 0; slice < sliceNumber; slice++) {
            float slicePercentage0 = ((float) (slice) / sliceNumber);
            float slicePercentage1 = ((float) (slice + 1) / sliceNumber);
            double phi0 = slicePercentage0 * 2.0 * Math.PI;
            double phi1 = slicePercentage1 * 2.0 * Math.PI;
            float s0, s1;
            if (facingOut) {
                s0 = 1.0f - slicePercentage0;
                s1 = 1.0f - slicePercentage1;
            } else {
                s0 = slicePercentage0;
                s1 = slicePercentage1;
            }
            double cosPhi0 = Math.cos(phi0);
            double sinPhi0 = Math.sin(phi0);
            double cosPhi1 = Math.cos(phi1);
            double sinPhi1 = Math.sin(phi1);

            float x0 = (float) (sinTheta0 * cosPhi0);
            float y0 = (float) cosTheta0;
            float z0 = (float) (sinTheta0 * sinPhi0);

            float x1 = (float) (sinTheta0 * cosPhi1);
            float y1 = (float) cosTheta0;
            float z1 = (float) (sinTheta0 * sinPhi1);

            float x2 = (float) (sinTheta1 * cosPhi0);
            float y2 = (float) cosTheta1;
            float z2 = (float) (sinTheta1 * sinPhi0);

            float x3 = (float) (sinTheta1 * cosPhi1);
            float y3 = (float) cosTheta1;
            float z3 = (float) (sinTheta1 * sinPhi1);

            vertices[vertexCount + 0] = x0;
            vertices[vertexCount + 1] = y0;
            vertices[vertexCount + 2] = z0;

            vertices[vertexCount + 3] = x1;
            vertices[vertexCount + 4] = y1;
            vertices[vertexCount + 5] = z1;

            vertices[vertexCount + 6] = x2;
            vertices[vertexCount + 7] = y2;
            vertices[vertexCount + 8] = z2;

            vertices[vertexCount + 9] = x3;
            vertices[vertexCount + 10] = y3;
            vertices[vertexCount + 11] = z3;

            if (facingOut) {
                normals[vertexCount + 0] = x0;
                normals[vertexCount + 1] = y0;
                normals[vertexCount + 2] = z0;

                normals[vertexCount + 3] = x1;
                normals[vertexCount + 4] = y1;
                normals[vertexCount + 5] = z1;

                normals[vertexCount + 6] = x2;
                normals[vertexCount + 7] = y2;
                normals[vertexCount + 8] = z2;

                normals[vertexCount + 9] = x3;
                normals[vertexCount + 10] = y3;
                normals[vertexCount + 11] = z3;
            } else {
                normals[vertexCount + 0] = -x0;
                normals[vertexCount + 1] = -y0;
                normals[vertexCount + 2] = -z0;

                normals[vertexCount + 3] = -x1;
                normals[vertexCount + 4] = -y1;
                normals[vertexCount + 5] = -z1;

                normals[vertexCount + 6] = -x2;
                normals[vertexCount + 7] = -y2;
                normals[vertexCount + 8] = -z2;

                normals[vertexCount + 9] = -x3;
                normals[vertexCount + 10] = -y3;
                normals[vertexCount + 11] = -z3;
            }

            texCoords[texCoordCount + 0] = s0;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 1] = t0;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 2] = s1;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 3] = t0;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 4] = s0;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 5] = t1;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 6] = s1;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 7] = t1;

            // one quad looking from outside toward center
            //
            // @formatter:off
            //
            // s1 --> s0
            //
            // t0 1-----0
            // | | |
            // v | |
            // t1 3-----2
            //
            // @formatter:on
            //
            // Note that tex_coord t increase from top to bottom because the
            // texture image is loaded upside down.
            if (facingOut) {
                indices[indexCount + 0] = (char) (triangleCount + 0);
                indices[indexCount + 1] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);
                indices[indexCount + 2] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);

                indices[indexCount + 3] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);
                indices[indexCount + 4] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);
                indices[indexCount + 5] = (char) (triangleCount + 3);
            } else {
                indices[indexCount + 0] = (char) (triangleCount + 0);
                indices[indexCount + 1] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);
                indices[indexCount + 2] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);

                indices[indexCount + 3] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);
                indices[indexCount + 4] = (char) (triangleCount + 3);
                indices[indexCount + 5] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);
            }

            vertexCount += 12;
            texCoordCount += 8;
            indexCount += 6;
            triangleCount += 4;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you define 25%? By volume of the cylinder? By angle?

Comment: Take a look at createArc. It kind of does the opposite of what you want to do. But if it is in fact the opposite, you can might be able to use Area.subtract from a sphere to get what you want. https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/util/ShapeUtils.java

Comment: @NicolBolas By Angle (`Theta`)

Comment: @ControlAltDel I don't think these two APIs can be integrated. I have to modify the current code. Can't use another one. Return types are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code here is using [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) to calculate the sphere. `theta` is the variable that represents the up/down coordinate that you're interested in, and `theta` goes from 0 to PI. You want to go from PI/4 to 3PI/4. stackNumbers simply represent the number of divisions in the sphere, since you can see that it is used as a denominator for stack, which is the wrong variable to change. So you can make the following changes to the code instead. From:

```
double theta0 = stackPercentage0 * Math.PI;
double theta1 = stackPercentage1 * Math.PI;
```

to:

```
double startTheta = Math.PI / 4;
double endTheta = 3 * Math.PI / 4;
double theta0 = stackPercentage0 * (endTheta - startTheta) + startTheta;
double theta1 = stackPercentage1 * (endTheta - startTheta) + startTheta;
```

And since you aren't using the caps you need to change the start and end stack numbers to reflect that:

```
for (int stack = 1; stack < stackNumber - 1; stack++) { // old
for (int stack = 0; stack < stackNumber; stack++) { // new
```

Also, you because you have more body faces now, you need to update the appropriate container for them. Replace `(stackNumber - 2)` with `(stackNumber - 1)`.

Comment: The first modification (for `theta`) seems valid. But did you notice in the code that the body is separate from the caps?! You were correct on the `for(int stack=0` part (the upper part of my image is not cut anymore), but when I change `stack < stackNumber - 1` to `stack < stackNumber` I get runtime error. Your logic seems correct (the bottom part of my image IS cut). Apparently we should modify somewhere a bit...

Comment: Yes, I know that they're separate. What's the runtime error?

Comment: Ok, I noticed your edit for `stackNumber - 1` which works now. But the very bottom part of image (probably last stack) is cut now as I compare my original image with what I see in the output.

Comment: My engine shows unclear error (or maybe I don't know how to show them), but probably some sort of buffer overflow I believe.

Comment: Great! Body is perfect. How can I get the upper and lower halves then?

Comment: I was using `theta0/=4` and `theta1/=4` for both body and cap code, but one bottom-most stack is missing!

Comment: Got it. I just changed `(stackNumber - 2)` to `(stackNumber - 1)` in the same way as middle body. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I had an urgent and quick follow-up about this question. I was trying to split the middle sphere as you have here into 4 parts (as shown in the picture). I already did it for a full sphere simply with `phi0/=4;` and `phi1/=4;` in the slice loop and it was working. I did the same for the middle body, but I see a small edge problem on top and bottom. Is there anything wrong?