# How to draw and split a sphere into 6 parts (in code)

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, 3d, mesh

This is a follow-up question of my previous question in here: [How to draw the middle half of a sphere (in code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149600/how-to-draw-the-middle-half-of-a-sphere-in-code)

We've already created the middle half of a sphere. My problem is how can I split the middle part into 4 similar parts (each as shown with 90 degree)? I already did 4 vertical parts for a full sphere simply with `phi0/=4;` and `phi1/=4;` in the slice loop and it was working perfectly. I did the same trick for the middle body that we got, but I see some edging problems on top and bottom boundaries when the top cap and bottom cap are connecting to the body. What is wrong with my approach?

Here is the popular code for generating a sphere programmatically:

UPDATE: It is not easy for me to take a screenshot, now. So basically when I texture all parts, I see they are not smoothly connected at the top and bottom boundaries. Splitting within the middle body is just fine.

[image]
[image]

```
private void generateSphere(int stackNumber, int sliceNumber, boolean facingOut) {
    int capVertexNumber = 3 * sliceNumber;
    int bodyVertexNumber = 4 * sliceNumber * (stackNumber - 2);
    int vertexNumber = (2 * capVertexNumber) + bodyVertexNumber;
    int triangleNumber = (2 * capVertexNumber) + (6 * sliceNumber * (stackNumber - 2));

    vertices = new float[3 * vertexNumber];
    normals = new float[3 * vertexNumber];
    texCoords = new float[2 * vertexNumber];
    indices = new char[triangleNumber];

    // bottom cap
    // createCap(stackNumber, sliceNumber, false, facingOut);

    // body
    createBody(stackNumber, sliceNumber, facingOut);

    // top cap
    createCap(stackNumber, sliceNumber, true, facingOut);
}

private void createCap(int stackNumber, int sliceNumber, boolean top, boolean facingOut) {

    float stackPercentage0;
    float stackPercentage1;

    if (!top) {
        stackPercentage0 = ((float) (stackNumber - 1) / stackNumber);
        stackPercentage1 = 1.0f;

    } else {
        stackPercentage0 = (1.0f / stackNumber);
        stackPercentage1 = 0.0f;
    }

    float t0 = stackPercentage0;
    float t1 = stackPercentage1;
    double theta0 = stackPercentage0 * Math.PI;
    double theta1 = stackPercentage1 * Math.PI;
    double cosTheta0 = Math.cos(theta0);
    double sinTheta0 = Math.sin(theta0);
    double cosTheta1 = Math.cos(theta1);
    double sinTheta1 = Math.sin(theta1);

    for (int slice = 0; slice < sliceNumber; slice++) {
        float slicePercentage0 = ((float) (slice) / sliceNumber);
        float slicePercentage1 = ((float) (slice + 1) / sliceNumber);
        double phi0 = slicePercentage0 * 2.0 * Math.PI;
        double phi1 = slicePercentage1 * 2.0 * Math.PI;
        float s0, s1;
        if (facingOut) {
            s0 = 1 - slicePercentage0;
            s1 = 1 - slicePercentage1;
        } else {
            s0 = slicePercentage0;
            s1 = slicePercentage1;
        }
        float s2 = (s0 + s1) / 2.0f;
        double cosPhi0 = Math.cos(phi0);
        double sinPhi0 = Math.sin(phi0);
        double cosPhi1 = Math.cos(phi1);
        double sinPhi1 = Math.sin(phi1);

        float x0 = (float) (sinTheta0 * cosPhi0);
        float y0 = (float) cosTheta0;
        float z0 = (float) (sinTheta0 * sinPhi0);

        float x1 = (float) (sinTheta0 * cosPhi1);
        float y1 = (float) cosTheta0;
        float z1 = (float) (sinTheta0 * sinPhi1);

        float x2 = (float) (sinTheta1 * cosPhi0);
        float y2 = (float) cosTheta1;
        float z2 = (float) (sinTheta1 * sinPhi0);

        vertices[vertexCount + 0] = x0;
        vertices[vertexCount + 1] = y0;
        vertices[vertexCount + 2] = z0;

        vertices[vertexCount + 3] = x1;
        vertices[vertexCount + 4] = y1;
        vertices[vertexCount + 5] = z1;

        vertices[vertexCount + 6] = x2;
        vertices[vertexCount + 7] = y2;
        vertices[vertexCount + 8] = z2;

        if (facingOut) {
            normals[vertexCount + 0] = x0;
            normals[vertexCount + 1] = y0;
            normals[vertexCount + 2] = z0;

            normals[vertexCount + 3] = x1;
            normals[vertexCount + 4] = y1;
            normals[vertexCount + 5] = z1;

            normals[vertexCount + 6] = x2;
            normals[vertexCount + 7] = y2;
            normals[vertexCount + 8] = z2;
        } else {
            normals[vertexCount + 0] = -x0;
            normals[vertexCount + 1] = -y0;
            normals[vertexCount + 2] = -z0;

            normals[vertexCount + 3] = -x1;
            normals[vertexCount + 4] = -y1;
            normals[vertexCount + 5] = -z1;

            normals[vertexCount + 6] = -x2;
            normals[vertexCount + 7] = -y2;
            normals[vertexCount + 8] = -z2;
        }

        texCoords[texCoordCount + 0] = s0;
        texCoords[texCoordCount + 1] = t0;
        texCoords[texCoordCount + 2] = s1;
        texCoords[texCoordCount + 3] = t0;
        texCoords[texCoordCount + 4] = s2;
        texCoords[texCoordCount + 5] = t1;

        if ((facingOut && top) || (!facingOut && !top)) {
            indices[indexCount + 0] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);
            indices[indexCount + 1] = (char) (triangleCount + 0);
            indices[indexCount + 2] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);
        } else {
            indices[indexCount + 0] = (char) (triangleCount + 0);
            indices[indexCount + 1] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);
            indices[indexCount + 2] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);
        }

        vertexCount += 9;
        texCoordCount += 6;
        indexCount += 3;
        triangleCount += 3;
    }

}

private void createBody(int stackNumber, int sliceNumber, boolean facingOut) {
    for (int stack = 1; stack < stackNumber - 1; stack++) {
        float stackPercentage0 = ((float) (stack) / stackNumber);
        float stackPercentage1 = ((float) (stack + 1) / stackNumber);

        float t0 = stackPercentage0;
        float t1 = stackPercentage1;

        double theta0 = stackPercentage0 * Math.PI;
        double theta1 = stackPercentage1 * Math.PI;
        double cosTheta0 = Math.cos(theta0);
        double sinTheta0 = Math.sin(theta0);
        double cosTheta1 = Math.cos(theta1);
        double sinTheta1 = Math.sin(theta1);

        for (int slice = 0; slice < sliceNumber; slice++) {
            float slicePercentage0 = ((float) (slice) / sliceNumber);
            float slicePercentage1 = ((float) (slice + 1) / sliceNumber);
            double phi0 = slicePercentage0 * 2.0 * Math.PI;
            double phi1 = slicePercentage1 * 2.0 * Math.PI;
            float s0, s1;
            if (facingOut) {
                s0 = 1.0f - slicePercentage0;
                s1 = 1.0f - slicePercentage1;
            } else {
                s0 = slicePercentage0;
                s1 = slicePercentage1;
            }
            double cosPhi0 = Math.cos(phi0);
            double sinPhi0 = Math.sin(phi0);
            double cosPhi1 = Math.cos(phi1);
            double sinPhi1 = Math.sin(phi1);

            float x0 = (float) (sinTheta0 * cosPhi0);
            float y0 = (float) cosTheta0;
            float z0 = (float) (sinTheta0 * sinPhi0);

            float x1 = (float) (sinTheta0 * cosPhi1);
            float y1 = (float) cosTheta0;
            float z1 = (float) (sinTheta0 * sinPhi1);

            float x2 = (float) (sinTheta1 * cosPhi0);
            float y2 = (float) cosTheta1;
            float z2 = (float) (sinTheta1 * sinPhi0);

            float x3 = (float) (sinTheta1 * cosPhi1);
            float y3 = (float) cosTheta1;
            float z3 = (float) (sinTheta1 * sinPhi1);

            vertices[vertexCount + 0] = x0;
            vertices[vertexCount + 1] = y0;
            vertices[vertexCount + 2] = z0;

            vertices[vertexCount + 3] = x1;
            vertices[vertexCount + 4] = y1;
            vertices[vertexCount + 5] = z1;

            vertices[vertexCount + 6] = x2;
            vertices[vertexCount + 7] = y2;
            vertices[vertexCount + 8] = z2;

            vertices[vertexCount + 9] = x3;
            vertices[vertexCount + 10] = y3;
            vertices[vertexCount + 11] = z3;

            if (facingOut) {
                normals[vertexCount + 0] = x0;
                normals[vertexCount + 1] = y0;
                normals[vertexCount + 2] = z0;

                normals[vertexCount + 3] = x1;
                normals[vertexCount + 4] = y1;
                normals[vertexCount + 5] = z1;

                normals[vertexCount + 6] = x2;
                normals[vertexCount + 7] = y2;
                normals[vertexCount + 8] = z2;

                normals[vertexCount + 9] = x3;
                normals[vertexCount + 10] = y3;
                normals[vertexCount + 11] = z3;
            } else {
                normals[vertexCount + 0] = -x0;
                normals[vertexCount + 1] = -y0;
                normals[vertexCount + 2] = -z0;

                normals[vertexCount + 3] = -x1;
                normals[vertexCount + 4] = -y1;
                normals[vertexCount + 5] = -z1;

                normals[vertexCount + 6] = -x2;
                normals[vertexCount + 7] = -y2;
                normals[vertexCount + 8] = -z2;

                normals[vertexCount + 9] = -x3;
                normals[vertexCount + 10] = -y3;
                normals[vertexCount + 11] = -z3;
            }

            texCoords[texCoordCount + 0] = s0;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 1] = t0;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 2] = s1;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 3] = t0;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 4] = s0;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 5] = t1;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 6] = s1;
            texCoords[texCoordCount + 7] = t1;

            // one quad looking from outside toward center
            //
            // @formatter:off
            //
            // s1 --> s0
            //
            // t0 1-----0
            // | | |
            // v | |
            // t1 3-----2
            //
            // @formatter:on
            //
            // Note that tex_coord t increase from top to bottom because the
            // texture image is loaded upside down.
            if (facingOut) {
                indices[indexCount + 0] = (char) (triangleCount + 0);
                indices[indexCount + 1] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);
                indices[indexCount + 2] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);

                indices[indexCount + 3] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);
                indices[indexCount + 4] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);
                indices[indexCount + 5] = (char) (triangleCount + 3);
            } else {
                indices[indexCount + 0] = (char) (triangleCount + 0);
                indices[indexCount + 1] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);
                indices[indexCount + 2] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);

                indices[indexCount + 3] = (char) (triangleCount + 2);
                indices[indexCount + 4] = (char) (triangleCount + 3);
                indices[indexCount + 5] = (char) (triangleCount + 1);
            }

            vertexCount += 12;
            texCoordCount += 8;
            indexCount += 6;
            triangleCount += 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @meepzh thanks for your helps the other time.

Comment: Please can you show some screenshots showing what the current output looks like? It's not clear what problems you're currently having.

Comment: I updated the question. Real screenshot is not easy right now...

Comment: Popular code? What makes it popular? It looks about as inefficient as it gets. Starting with using double precision arithmetic, calculating normals that are completely unnecessary, etc. Anyway, the description is somewhat unclear to me. But one thing to look out for is that you will often need multiple vertices with the same coordinates, but different texture coordinates, to get proper texturing at seams.